# Blackscreen on Kubuntu after installation

Tags: kubuntu, amdgpu

I installed Kubuntu for that I enabled integrated graphics.

Then I set the initial display output to pci 1 output and disabled the ingrated grahics. Then I put the hdmi cable in the graphics card (amd r9 390) and boot. I just get a blackscreen with a not blinking underline. Pressing alt ctrl f1 does nothing but when i turn of the pc i see the kubuntu logo while the computer is turning of. Then i switchd back to integrated graphics but over that i m now getting a blackscreen with a blinking cursor and i can access the console there. I noticed that my gpu is a sea island one. I tried

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=1"

And

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1"

But it is not working.

Comment: Ok, I will try but I think the installer screen was black with the hdmi plugged in the graphics card

Comment: See: [My computer boots to a black screen during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076).  If this is new hardware, make sure it's connected properly and check for possible damage. Many dedicated GPUs also require additional power from the power supply.

Comment: No it is not new and I manged to run ubuntu and manjaro on it earlier this year

Comment: Is there a nomodeset in the grub line you boot with?